# slim skeleton framework Post Method gives "Method not allowed"

Tags: php, .htaccess, rest, slim

I tried almost everything
but I keep receiving

## Method not allowed

Method not allowed. Must be one of: 
            **POST**

The code that I'm using is:

```
$app->post('/ticket/new', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    // Create new book
    echo 'a;';
});
```

I'm trying on postman

```
method: post
url: /public/ticket/new
header: Content-Type application/javascript
```

Any clue will help me

`.htaccess` is ok:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Some hosts may require you to use the `RewriteBase` directive.
# If you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive, it should be the
# absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.
#
# RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Make sure you actually post to Slim and not something else. Curl example with headers is more helpful than Postman: curl --request POST --include http://www.example.com

Comment: The url is different, no? Declared `/ticket/new`, while requesting `/public/ticket/new`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
$app->map(['GET', 'POST'],'/ticket/new', function (Request $request, Response     $response) {
    // Create new book
    echo 'a;';
});
```